# Create edges from one traversal to another in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I use Gremlin API in Java.
Assume we have a traversal to persons and another traversal to locations that is quite long and dependent on the first:

```
GraphTraversal<?, Vertex> persons = g.V().has("prop", "value");
GraphTraversal<?, Vertex> locations = persons.out("place").has(..)..;
```

Now I want to link each person to the locations that correspond to that persons with a direct link, considering that some of these edges are already in place.

Which strategy would be good to do such links using Gremlin API in Java?

Comment: It would be nice if you could expand your question to show what you have tried so far and ideally include a small sample graph (some `addV` and `addE` steps) that will help in creating a good answer. It sounds like you want to add edges but only add them if they do not already exist. In general this can be done with a `coalesce` step. If you can expand your question it will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an easy way to link two streams of vertices with many to many relationship. But getting the set of objects and creating edge in loop as usually for one to many works for me:

```
Set<Object> personVertexIds = persons.id().toSet();
personVertexIds.forEach(id -> {
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> person = g.V(id).as("p");
    GraphTraversal<?, Vertex> locations = persons.out("place").has(..)..;
    locations.coalesce(inE("link").where(outV().where(P.eq("p"))),
          addE("link").from("p")).property("prop", value);
});
```